# sscanf and correct format file

Tags: c, linux, scanf

I have a problem with `sscanf` function. To be more specific I want read a float from a txt file (I want only one float for line) but `sscanf` doesn't recognize these situations:

```
3.4t
```

or

```
4.t6
```

or

```
4.5 6.5
```

or

```
(this is an empty line)
```

I use this code:

```
 #define LUNRIGA 200     

 char riga[LUNRIGA+1];

 while (fgets(riga,LUNRIGA,f) != NULL) {
      r = sscanf(riga,"%f",&numeri[i]);
      if (r == 1) { /* riga valida */
         printf("OK");
      }else{
         printf("Error");
         return 1; 
      }    
 }
```

Comment: Do you mean `fprintf` or `sscanf`?

Comment: sorry you are right. I'm going to modify my question. The problem is with sscanf

Comment: What would you want it to do with 4.t6 ?

Comment: See with the terminal "Error"

Answer (score 1):

`sscanf` is notoriously picky about the input. You will have better luck using `strtod` or `strtol` - they can read a value even if it's followed by junk. Change your code as follows:

```
#define LUNRIGA 200     

char riga[LUNRIGA+1];
char* tempPtr;

while (fgets(riga,LUNRIGA,f) != NULL) {
  numeri[i] = strtof( riga, &tempPtr );
  if (tempPtr > riga) { /* riga valida */
     printf("OK");
  }
  else {
     printf("Error");
     return 1; 
  }    
}
```

Note by the way that you don't seem to increment `i` in your loop - you might want to see if that's actually what you want, or if you would like to increment it every time you get a valid number (assuming you don't just want the last value, but all of them...)

As a little demo of the behavior of `strtod`, I wrote a few lines of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
  char* s1="123.45t";
  char* p1;
  char* s2 = "   notanumber";
  double d1, d2;
  d1 = strtod(s1, &p1);
  printf("the number is %.2lf; the pointer is now %p; string is at %p\n", d1, s1, p1);
  d2 = strtod(s2, &p1);
  printf("the number is %.2lf; the pointer is now %p; string is at %p\n", d2, s2, p1);
}
```

The output of this is:

```
The number is 123.45; the pointer is now 0x400668; string is at 0x40066e
The number is 0.00; the pointer is now 0x400670; string is at 0x400670
```

As you can see, when reading garbage the pointer returned points to the start of the string - indicating "failed". When it is successful, the pointer is pointing to "where I stopped reading", which is "after successfully converting a bit of string to double.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm going to use float. Not double or int numbers

Comment: @user2467899 Or `strtod()`. Really, don't use `scanf()`. It's evil. The other alternatives mentioned provide a much better solution. (And ya know, `double` can be converted to `float` implicitly.)

Comment: Actually, the problem is that `sscanf()` will happily convert all except the empty line into a number, but it will ignore (in this case) garbage characters like `t` or the second number.

Comment: @Floris ***`const`*** `char *p = "string literal";`, please.

Comment: @H2CO3 - can you explain why it matters? I honestly don't know. Perhaps you have a useful reference for me - always want to learn.

Comment: @Floris Because it indicates that you cannot modify the contents of the string, so the compiler will be able to notify you when you want to do something that's not allowed (like using `strtok()` on a string literal).

Comment: @H2CO3 I understand - but 1) I was writing a snippet to demonstrate something, and not going to forget what I was doing in under a dozen lines of code; and 2) Sometimes it is useful to overwrite a string even if it was initially a constant. As long as I know the space I have available. I can see where it can get one into trouble though. Should I change my habit? I'm an old dog... is this a new trick I need to learn?

Comment: @Floris "Sometimes it is useful to overwrite a string even if it was initially a constant." - yup, and I wasn't asking you to write `const char *const p = "foo";` either. The first `const` qualifies the characters, not the pointer. And yes, in my opinion you should definitely start using `const char *` for pointers to string literals if you haven't done so until now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure there's no junk on the line, you can use the `%n` directive to find out where conversion stops and decide what to do about what comes afterwards on the line:

```
char  riga[LUNRIGA];
float numeri[NUM_VALUES];
int   offset;
int   i;

for (i = 0; i < NUM_VALUES && fgets(riga, sizeof(riga), f) != NULL; i++)
{
    int r = sscanf(riga, "%f%n", &numeri[i], &offset);
    if (r == 1 && riga[offset] == '\n')
        printf("OK (got %f from <<%s>>\n", numeri[i], riga);
    else
    {
        printf("Error processing <<%s>>\n", riga);
        return 1; 
    }    
}
```

You can do some extra processing before the `sscanf()`, for example to check that you read a newline (so there isn't the residue of an extra long line still to be read) and to remove the newline (but then you need to change the condition).

Note the use of `sizeof(riga)`, and the check for not overflowing `numeri` by imposing a `for` loop on the code, and the presence of a newline at the end of each message printed.

Comment: `i` isn't being incremented in the OP loop, so no risk of overflowing... just overwriting.

Comment: Oh - yes, I forgot that I'd noticed and fixed that bug too!  I'm inclined to assume that was an oversight in the minimization process, but I may be being too charitable.

Comment: Charity is a virtue. Either way, your code is an improvement over the original. I like `sscanf` less and less for this kind of task, although your approach makes it "almost palatable". Except if the last line in the file doesn't have a newline...